How to combine a Toggle Button and a Slicer for Filtering a Table
I have a table where I am attempting to combine a toggle button and a slicer to filter the content.
The table ("Data") is located on the worksheet "Timeline". The toggle button is to simply hide/show the entire list of species, or only species that were located in a "Program" area.  The Slicer ("Slicer_Program") is to show data relevant to particular "Program" areas.
I need the filter in the table to update every time I use the toggle button to reflect what is selected in the slicer, and to update every time i use the slicer.
at the moment, if i have the slicer set to "Program A" and toggle the button to hide the species that were not found, It works fine.  However, if i change the slicer to show data from "Program B", the species which were not found in A but were found in B remain hidden, and the species which were found in B but not A remain visible despite wanting them to be hidden.  For it to work i need to toggle the button off and then back on every time i change the slicer setting.
Currently i have two toggle buttons using the code:
Private Sub ShowAll_Click()
Dim range_to_filter As Range
Set range_to_filter = Sheets("Timeline").Range("E5:E57")
range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"""
End Sub

Private Sub ShowPresent_Click()
Dim range_to_filter As Range
Set range_to_filter = Sheets("Timeline").Range("E5:E57")
range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>0"
End Sub

to hide and show the relevant rows of data.  I would prefer to have one button, and for it to automatically update every time the slicer selection is changed.

It's hard to tell what you're talking about. Could you backup your story with sample data, screenshots, and more code? Related to your posted code, when you filter a single column, the Field argument can only be 1. If you would filter on multiple columns, e.g. A5:J57, 5 would be fine. Also, the first criterion means different than a double-quote which doesn't seem likely to be your intent.
